# Pandas filter rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some values in the `risk` column that are neither, `Small`, `Medium` or `High`. I want to delete the rows with the value not being `Small`, `Medium` and `High`. I tried the following:

```
df = df[(df.risk == "Small") | (df.risk == "Medium") | (df.risk == "High")]
```

But this returns an empty DataFrame. How can I filter them correctly?

Comment: I've tried to create a dataframe with such data, and your string of code works properly. Could you give more information about what contains in dataframe and how do you generate it?

Comment: You requirement is a little unclear, if all your values can ever be small, mediu, or high and you want to drop rows that are any of these values then this will result in now rows so could you explain clearer what you require

Comment: Hmm.. your code is correct so I think you need to post data and code that reproduces your problem

Comment: For example, it would be useful to see what `df.risk.value_counts()` returns.

Comment: @EdChum. Your previous (now deleted post) had df = df[df.risk.isin(['Small','Medium','High'])]. That gave the desired result !

Comment: Before the advise by EdChum:In [154]:

df.risk.value_counts()
Out[154]:
Small     23520
Medium     6164
High        402
None        251

After code from EdChum the 'None' was gone. :-)

Comment: @ArtDijk OK I will undelete and edit my answer

Comment: Could you post some data though and also as @DSM suggests the output from df.risk.value_counts()

Comment: Do you want to just filter out 'None' values?

Comment: @ EdChum. I want to filter out all none Small, Medium or High values.

Comment: @ArtDijk well your code sample should've worked and it worked on my toy dataset, whilst my alternative suggestion works for you it'd be better to post some actual data if you can and the output from `df.risk.value_counts()`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you want:

```
df = df[(df.risk.isin(["Small","Medium","High"]))]
```

Example:

```
In [5]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'risk':['Small','High','Medium','Negligible', 'Very High']})
df

Out[5]:

         risk
0       Small
1        High
2      Medium
3  Negligible
4   Very High

[5 rows x 1 columns]

In [6]:

df[df.risk.isin(['Small','Medium','High'])]

Out[6]:

     risk
0   Small
1    High
2  Medium

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Aren't these logical statements equivalent to the one provided by author?

Comment: I've tryed your example with author's slicing - it works correctly

Comment: @MikhailElizarev it is slightly different but the OP's question is a little unclear as what they are doing would result in no results

Comment: To make it mor universally, one could do this instead: `df[df["risk"].isin(['Small','Medium','High'])]`

Answer (score 4):

Another nice and readable approach is the following:

```
small_risk = df["risk"] == "Small"
medium_risk = df["risk"] == "Medium"
high_risk = df["risk"] == "High"
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
df[small_risk | medium_risk | high_risk]
```

or

```
df[small_risk & medium_risk]
```

Comment: df[small_risk & medium_risk] always returns nothing.
df["risk"] cannot be simultaneously equal "Small" AND "Medium"

Comment: That example was to show that AND gate in cases it’s applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query('risk in ["Small","Medium","High"]')
```

You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with `@`. For example:

```
lst = ["Small","Medium","High"]
df.query("risk in @lst")
```

If the column name is multiple words, e.g. `"risk factor"`, you can refer to it by surrounding it with backticks `` ` ` ``:

```
df.query('`risk factor` in @lst')
```

`query` method comes in handy if you need to chain multiple conditions. For example, the outcome of the following filter:

```
df[df['risk factor'].isin(lst) & (df['value']**2 > 2) & (df['value']**2 < 5)]
```

can be derived using the following expression:

```
df.query('`risk factor` in @lst and 2 < value**2 < 5')
```