# Pandas filter not working as expected

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which I need to remove certain rows that do not match a regex pattern in a given column. The column I need to run the regex against is formatted: `lastname,firstname`, and I want to remove all rows in that column that do not match that format. I am trying to use the pandas filter method, and I have tried using the command this way:
`edited_df = idf['Name'].filter(regex="([aA-zZ]*)([,]{1})([aA-zZ]*)")` and
`edited_df = idf['Name'].filter(regex="/([aA-zZ]*)([,]{1})([aA-zZ]*)/")`.
However, doing that produces this error:
`TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`
The result of `type(idf['Name'])` is a series, and each entry in it is a string, per `type(idf['CIO'][1])`.
I saw this question [Pandas filter rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323974/pandas-filter-rows), but I want to make my program more modular and not have to adjust a list of names every time there is a name added.
I tested my regex at http://pythex.org/ with test strings and it matched as expected, so I am assuming I am using the filter method incorrectly. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Also, a less important matter is if it is possible to access the capture groups created from the regex in the modified dataframe.

Comment: Can you try `idf[idf['Name'].str.contains(r"([aA-zZ]*)([,]{1})([aA-zZ]*)")]`

Comment: @EdChum I get this error, `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` even after using fillna (`idf['Name'].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)`).

Comment: Try dropping the `NaN` values first so `idf['Name'].dropna()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to EdChum's comments, here is how to solve this problem:
First, drop the `NaN` values using:

```
idf.dropna(subset=['Name'], inplace=True)
```

Then, use `str.contains` instead of filter:

```
edited_df = idf[idf['Name'].str.contains(r"([aA-zZ]*)([,]{1})([aA-zZ]*)")]
```