# Filtering data through command line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm currently working at a program that analyses data from a tsv file. I created the basic functions, but I need to further filter the data frame. I have the columns Carrier, origin and date that I need to use for the filtering. That's my approach for now:

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd
# Parsing arguments. You must not modify these lines!
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("statistic", choices=["avg", "max"], help="Which statistic should be run?")
parser.add_argument("variable", choices=["distance", "delay"], help="What variable should be used for the calculation?")
parser.add_argument("tsvfile", help="Name of data file to be analyzed")
parser.add_argument("--carrier", dest="carrier", help="Comma-separated list of airline codes for those airlines whose flights should be included")
#parser.add_argument("--date", dest="date", help="Departure dates for flights to be included")
#parser.add_argument("--origin", dest="origin", help="Departure dates for flights to be included")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Start here with the rest of the program....

#accesing the values
stats = args.statistic
var = args.variable
car = args.carrier
#the_date = args.date
#origin = args.origin

#opening the file
file = pd.read_csv(args.tsvfile,  sep='\t')



#printing the max distance
if stats == "max" and var == "distance":
    print(max(file["DISTANCE"]))

#printing the max delay
if stats == "max" and var =="delay":
    print(max(file["DEPARTURE_DELAY"]))

#printing the avg delay
if stats == "avg" and var == "delay":
    no_of_planes_delay = 0
sum_delay = 0
for number in file["DEPARTURE_DELAY"]:
    if number > 0:
        no_of_planes_delay += 1
        sum_delay = sum_delay + number
    if number <= 0:
        no_of_planes_delay +=1
        sum_delay = sum_delay + 0
average_delay = sum_delay/no_of_planes_delay
print(round(average_delay, 1))

#printing the avg distance
if stats == "avg" and var == "distance":
    sum_distance = 0
no_of_planes = 0
for number in file["DISTANCE"]:
    no_of_planes +=1
    sum_distance = sum_distance + number           
average_distance = (sum_distance/no_of_planes)
print(round(average_distance, 1))`
```

so I need to apply through the command line those filters eg python flights.py --carrier AA,DL --origin JFK avg delay flights.tsv
Does anyone know how could I use my functions and filter further the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

For filterng see [Pandas filter rows based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323974/pandas-filter-rows-based-on-multiple-conditions)

```py
carrier_list = args.carrier.split(',')
file[file.Carrier.isin(carrier_list)]
```

You can avoid those if conditions using dictionaries

```py
    var_to_col_mapping = {
       'distance':'DISTANCE',
       'delay':'DEPARTURE_DELAY'
    }

    def calc_avg(df):
       # logic to calculate average goes here
       pass

    def calc_max(df):
       # logic to calculate max goes here
       pass

    stat_to_func_mapping = {
       'max':calc_max,
       'avg':calc_avg
    }

    print( stat_to_func_mapping[stats](file[var_to_col_mapping[var]]) )
```